# LINQ Join for Orderby only

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-3.5

I am trying to run this code:

```
ItemTaxonomy iTaxonomy = from itemTaxonomy in connection.ItemTaxonomy
                         where itemTaxonomy.Item.ID == itemView.ID
                         orderby itemTaxonomy.Taxonomy.Name
                         select itemTaxonomy;
```

When I compiled it I get the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 
>   `'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable<Website.Models.ItemTaxonomy>'` to 
>   `'Website.Models.ItemTaxonomy'`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I believe the issue is with `orderby itemTaxonomy.Taxonomy.Name` but I am just trying to order by the name of Taxonomy items instead of their IDs.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the problem is that the result is a *sequence* whereas your variable is a *single item*.

Given that you're expressing ordering, you must be expecting multiple values - so what do you want to do with them? Options:

- Use `First()`:

  ```
  ItemTaxonomy iTaxonomy = (from itemTaxonomy in connection.ItemTaxonomy
                            where itemTaxonomy.Item.ID == itemView.ID
                            orderby itemTaxonomy.Taxonomy.Name
                            select itemTaxonomy).First();
  ```

  This will return the `ItemTaxonomy` with the earliest name out of all the ones with the appropriate item ID.
- Change your variable type:

  ```
  IEnumerable<ItemTaxonomy> taxonomies = 
      from itemTaxonomy in connection.ItemTaxonomy
      where itemTaxonomy.Item.ID == itemView.ID
      orderby itemTaxonomy.Taxonomy.Name
      select itemTaxonomy;
  ```

  Now you've got a sequence of taxonomies to deal with, instead of a single item.

Comment: Thanks!  That was silly of me.  I totally missed that I didn't have the results setup as a list.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be capturing a *single* value from a *query*. Try:

```
var iTaxonomy = from itemTaxonomy in connection.ItemTaxonomy
                where itemTaxonomy.Item.ID == itemView.ID
                orderby itemTaxonomy.Taxonomy.Name
                select itemTaxonomy;
```

or to be more explicit:

```
IQueryable<ItemTaxonomy> iTaxonomy = ...
```

If you *do* want a single item, use `,First()` or `.Single()`.

Answer (score 0):

The LINQ query returns a set (`IEnumerable<T>`) of `ItemTaxonomy` objects, which you are trying to assign to a variable of type `ItemTaxonomy`.

You need to change the type of the variable to `IEnumerable<ItemTaxonomy>`.  (Or call `First()`)